# How to detect an application is already installed and hence open that application in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-7.1

I am writing a windows Phone 7.1 Application and i want to detect whether an application is already installed or not. After determining that it is available then i need to open that application. I do have the Publisher ID for both the applications. Is it possible?

Please advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each app is sandboxed. Therefore you cannot tell which apps are installed and you cannot launch apps.

For some file types such as pdf, doc etc., you can launch them from your app in the phone's browser using a remote URL (local files will not work), and the browser will open the correct app and view the file. But this is limited the Microsoft apps and a few partners.

Comment: Thank you for the Reply. So even if i know the publisher id, still i will not be able to launch or detect it? WHat about this Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment namespace?

Comment: That was added in Windows Phone 8. I have never tried it but it looks like most of the methods are listed as not to be used from an app.

Answer (score 0):

There is mostly the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024438/windows-phone-navigate-between-apps/21025022#21025022). You can browse only your own apps, with your own Developer Id. And as Jon said, it's only Windows Phone 8 feature.